# Working authentication in functional testing

Tags: symfony, authentication, phpunit, functional-testing

This example is not working: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/testing/simulating_authentication.html

$session = $this->client->getContainer(); in login function return null.
Is any actual way for functional testing?